# XING - how to deep link both on Android on iOS?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, deep-linking, xing

How to deep link to specific profile in XING app both on Android and iOS?

On iOS I have figured out that I can open XING app using this code:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "xing://"), options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

But how can I open specific profile?

I would like also to know to do that on Android.

I will be very glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS the app scheme has to be either `xing://profiles/[username]` or `xing://profiles/[userId]`. I can imagine that it's similar on Android.